# pandas groupby offsets different start

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, offset, pandas-groupby

I have a simple offset question that I cannot seem to find the answer for in the other previous posts. I am trying to groupby weeks, but the default `df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1W'))` gives me the groupby starting on Sunday.

Say for instance I want this groupby to start on Tuesday. I tried to naively add `pd.DateOffset(days=2)` as an additional argument but that did not seem to work.

Comment: `df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1W-Mon'))`

Comment: thanks, you can mark your comment as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Offset strings can include a component that specifies when the type of period should start.

In your case, you want `W-Tue`

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('W-Tue'))
```